# Generated columns with Typorm in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I want to generate a column with typeorm but it's not working,
I am using PostgreSQL and I followed this article, it's said that is supported by typeorm
https://wanago.io/2021/11/29/generated-columns-postgresql-typeorm/

this is an example:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
 
@Entity()
class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;
 
  @Column()
  public firstName: string;
 
  @Column()
  public lastName: string;
 
  @Column({
    generatedType: 'STORED',
    asExpression: `'firstName' || ' ' || 'lastName'`
  })
  fullName: string;
}
```

any idea how to do it ?

Comment: plz check that `synchronize: true` . its not recommended in production.

Comment: I am in development mode and yes it's `synchronize: true`

Comment: then you have to restart after changes in entity. any error or something?

Comment: I didn't get anything but when I delete the column from the Postgre then restart this is what I get `query: ALTER TABLE "User " ADD "fullName" character varying NOT NULL`
I also trie to change the expression: 
`
  @Column({ generatedType: "STORED", asExpression: "concat(`firstName`,' ',`lastName`)"})
    fullName: string;
`
nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I was using an old version of Typeorm (@0.2.28) and the feature was supported in postgres in the version @0.2.42